# Gridview custom paging with full text search

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

"I want to implement Gridview custom paging with full text search, with each individual page being bound to only 10 results/records.
My current setup fetches all the search results (rows) on each button click but displays just 10, making it very resource intensive. If it is of any consequence, in my current pagination setup I have first, next, last and previous buttons beside the actual page numbers.

I would like to retain the same scheme but only have it fetch up to 10 results for each page and display as many at any given time.

Should I work on adapting this particular method:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5?
If yes, do you have any suggestions as to how i could go about doing so in my case? If not, please suggest some alternatives?"

Answer (score 0):

To fetch all the data while populating the grid for the first time is not a correct approach I think.

Depending on the page number and number of data that needs to be fetched, you need to get only that data from the database by sending the page number and page size qith your query.
So, when you click on First, Next, Previous and Last you send the page number and page size and get the data from database by calculating the total number of records.

Hope this provided you with an alternative approach.

Thanks!!

Comment: I think you are refering a right link posted in your question.